# Is it possible to make a webpage in FireFox take up the full window (no address-bar, etc.)?

Tags: firefox, browser, firefox-addon, fullscreen, address-bar

I've been trying to use FireFox as a simple window for a webpage that I will not be leaving, so I don't need the address-bar or close buttons, but I would like to keep my task bar visible (i.e. I do not want to simply go full screen). The gists of what I am trying to achieve is a "full window mode". Is there an add on that allows this? Preferably, I'd like an add on that can easily be turned on and off.

To elaborate, I may have the window only be half of the screen, so a full screen mode that leaves the task bar visible would not be sufficient.

Comment: Have you Googled, e.g. `firefox full screen html`?

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=firefox+kiosk+mode

Comment: @Pekka웃 yes, I have.

Comment: @Quentin I've tried that as well, but as I mentioned, I still need my taskbar to be visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can come close to this with some simple JavaScript, just a [bookmarklet](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=bookmarklet), which will open the currently viewed URL in a window with most of the info/action bars hidden:

```
javascript:void(window.open(location.href,"_blank","outerWidth=1000,outerHeight=650,top=0,left=250,menubar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,personalbar=no,status=no"))
```

You can get close to maximized with specifying appropriate numbers for `outerWidth=1000,outerHeight=650,top=0,left=250` which match your screen size, but you will not get quite what you can do when maximized.

You can then maximize the window. Which gives you:
[image: maximized window, JavaScript]

[`Window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) requires chrome privileges in order to hide the titlebar and locationbar which means an add-on must do it.  You can then use add-ons to get the rest of the way.

Using the [*Hide Caption Titlebar Plus*](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/hide-caption-titlebar-plus-sma/) add-on (with appropriate options selected) will get you to a maximized window of:
[image: maximized window, Hide Caption Titlebar Plus]

And with the addition of the add-on [*Hide Navigation Bar*](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/hide-navigation-bar/?src=search), maximized and hitting the default <kbd>F2</kbd> to hide the locationbar you get:
[image: maximized window, Hide Navigation Bar]

**Non-maximized:**
You also asked that it provide removal of the various action/status/tool bars when not maximized. These add-ons will do so.

**Easily turning them on and off:**
*Hide Navigation Bar* only hides the location bar if you hit <kbd>F2</kbd>. *Hide Caption Titlebar Plus* is a restartless add-on and thus can be enabled/disabled at will from `about:addons` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>).  It can also be set to mostly affect only maximized windows, so may not be something you need to enable/disable on a regular basis.

Personally, if this was something I wanted, I would set up a separate [Firefox profile](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles) which has these add-ons and the home page as the one I wanted displayed.  I would then set up a shortcut that automatically opens that page and shows what I want. You may need to use something like the add-on [Session Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/session-manager/) to automatically restore the maximized window, but the default functionality in Firefox may be sufficient.  In order to have a shortcut that brings up another Firefox profile automatically, you will need to set the Target to something like:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -no-remote -P "your profile name"
```

This would allow you to bring up the page you wanted with a single click and not have the configuration disturb your normal use of Firefox. It would also be something that you would not need to mess around with enabling/disabling on a regular basis.

**Many ways to do this:**
There are, probably, many different combinations of add-ons which will get you to a similar look.  There is, perhaps, even a single one which will do so. You should do some research on your own to find a combination that works for you. For the profile I was initially using to test, I did not need the *Hide Navigation Bar* add-on to hide the locationbar as that functionality was covered in a different add-on. However, if starting with a stock profile these two add-ons will get you to where it sounds like you want to be.

**Taskbar is visible:**
For all of the above images: If I had taken a shot of my entire desktop, you would see that that the Windows Taskbar is still visible (the Firefox window is just maximized, not full-screen). The above images are not full-screen for privacy reasons. I do not desire to share the windows I have open and my taskbar configuration. If I have the time later, I will re-take the window shots as full-screen shots after a clean re-boot.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I can tell you've researched this thoroughly :)